# Target last letter while typing with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I m trying to add a small typing effect in an input field. But I would like to only target the letter being typed, leaving the ones already typed alone.

```
$(".field").keydown(function() {
$('.field').css('font-size','25px');
});
$(".field").keyup(function() {
$('.field').css('font-size','15px');
});
```

Comment: Try `.keypress()` instead.

Comment: By "target" do you mean "apply a CSS style to"? In short, you want to have the most recent letter be large while a key is down and then become smaller on keyup?

Comment: You can't target a single letter, other than the `::first-letter` pseudo-element, of any element with CSS without wrapping it in its own element, such as a `span`. And `input`s can't contain any child nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with just a text box.  Here is a proof of concept for one possible solution to this.  If you would like me to help you come up with something more tailored to what you need specifically please let me know.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUcRA/)

I used the keyup event and separate p and span tags to make it work.

**HTML**

```
<input class='inBox'></input>
<div class='overlay'>
  <p class='text'></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input {
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 16px;
}
.lastLetter {
  color: blue;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.inBox').on('keyup', function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  $('.text').html(str.slice(0, -1) + 
                  '<span class="lastLetter">' +
                  str.charAt(str.length-1) + 
                  '</span>');
});
```